# Create Trigger for audit table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Newbie here. i needed audit triggers for my db tables in phpmyadmin and a friend recommended a guide to follow but im stuck and need help. below is the code.

Sample table (accounts table):

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `account_no` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `initial_balance` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `total_balance` double NOT NULL,
 `note` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_default` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Below is my audit table for accounts table:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts_audit_log` (
 accounts_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 old_row_data JSON,
 new_row_data JSON,
 dml_type ENUM('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE') NOT NULL,
 dml_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 dml_created_by VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`accounts_id`,`dml_type`,`dml_timestamp`)
)
```

added the following triggers using phpmyadmin's triggers tab under the accounts table.

Insert;

```
INSERT INTO accounts_audit_log (
        accounts_id,
        old_row_data,
        new_row_data,
        dml_type,
        dml_timestamp,
        dml_created_by
    )
    VALUES(
        NEW.id,
        null,
        JSON_OBJECT(
            "account_no", NEW.account_no,
            "name", NEW.name,
            "initial_balance", NEW.initial_balance,
            "total_balance", NEW.total_balance,
            "note", NEW.note,
            "is_default", NEW.is_default,
            "is_active", NEW.is_active,
            "created_at", NEW.created_at,
            "updated_at", NEW.updated_at
        ),
        'INSERT',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        @logged_user,
        @transaction_timestamp
    )
```

Update;

```
INSERT INTO accounts_audit_log (
        accounts_id,
        old_row_data,
        new_row_data,
        dml_type,
        dml_timestamp,
        dml_created_by
    )
    VALUES(
        NEW.id,
        JSON_OBJECT(
            "account_no", OLD.account_no,
            "name", NEW.name,
            "initial_balance", OLD.initial_balance,
            "total_balance", OLD.total_balance,
            "note", OLD.note,
            "is_default", OLD.is_default,
            "is_active", OLD.is_active,
            "created_at", OLD.created_at,
            "updated_at", OLD.updated_at
        ),      
        JSON_OBJECT(
            "account_no", NEW.account_no,
            "name", NEW.name,
            "initial_balance", NEW.initial_balance,
            "total_balance", NEW.total_balance,
            "note", NEW.note,
            "is_default", NEW.is_default,
            "is_active", NEW.is_active,
            "created_at", NEW.created_at,
            "updated_at", NEW.updated_at
        ),
        'UPDATE',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        @logged_user,
        @transaction_timestamp
    )
```

Delete;

```
INSERT INTO accounts_audit_log (
        accounts_id,
        old_row_data,
        new_row_data,
        dml_type,
        dml_timestamp,
        dml_created_by
    )
    VALUES(
        OLD.id,
        JSON_OBJECT(
            "account_no", OLD.account_no,
            "name", OLD.name,
            "initial_balance", OLD.initial_balance,
            "total_balance", OLD.total_balance,
            "note", OLD.note,
            "is_default", OLD.is_default,
            "is_active", OLD.is_active,
            "created_at", OLD.created_at,
            "updated_at", OLD.updated_at
        ),
        null,
        'DELETE',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        @logged_user,
        @transaction_timestamp
    )
```

Now when i try to edit accounts table to see if the triggers work i get:
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. cant really determine what is wrong. can anyone help? if anyone can also propose an easier code i can implement that will achieve the same function ill be greatful. thanks.

Comment: If you want a history, consider [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/).

Comment: Your `values` list have 7 items while the table has 6 columns.

Comment: @danblack how do i fix it please?

Comment: Compare the column names to the values, there's one that obviously doesn't match. Welcome to SO, not a answer site, but a help site.

Comment: The `@transaction_timestamp` seems to be the extra value, the table does not have anything for this after the `dml_created_by`. Basically what the error means, is that there is a mismatch between the `accounts_audit_log (accounts_id, old_row_data, new_row_data, dml_type, dml_timestamp, dml_created_by)` which has 6 parameters, and then the `VALUES (....)` portion has 7 parameters. Side note: instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` why not have that as a default at the table level, and that will not even to be included with the query since the DB will set it for you.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks a lot. that was clear enough for me to get the error out and have the trigger working.